# Java wrap UTF-8 text?

Tags: java, utf-8, word-wrap

I need to simply wrap long text to display it in a few lines. I tried the default snippet:

```
String s = "Español texto aquí";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

int i = 0;
while (i + 20 < sb.length() && (i = sb.lastIndexOf(" ", i + 20)) != -1) {
sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

but with Spanish text I get wrong symbols in output. How do I wrap non-English text?

Comment: There is no usage of UTF-8 in your question.

Comment: @MarkByers Well, what I meant - I cannot wrap non-English text this way

Comment: There is no use of anything specific to non-English characters, either. You are breaking at the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has one of the best handling of UTF-8 text I've seen (it internally uses UTF-16).

The only thing dependant on OS or encoding here is the line separator character you're using. You might try

```
System.lineSeparator()  // Java 7 only
```

or

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

instead of `\n`.

If that doesn't help either, the problem is probably in the console/terminal you're reading the result from, not the code. Make sure the source .java file is saved as UTF-8, try redirecting the output to a file and not console.

Comment: seems the problem was entirely in java class in android app

Answer (score 5):

```
String s = "Español texto aquí texto aquí Español texto aquí";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

int i = 0;
while (i + 20 < sb.length() && (i = sb.lastIndexOf(" ", i + 20)) != -1) {
  sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

prints

```
Español texto aquí
texto aquí Español
texto aquí
```

Now, I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: strange.. because I have weird symbols in the resulting text in my Android app

Comment: it is probably a property of the output terminal. try writing it to a file or something.

Comment: Then the issue is not with the code you posted, but somewhere else. Maybe the string gets read wrong, or written out wrong (a font charset issue, for example).

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready solution for that.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text

```
String s = "Español texto aquí texto aquí Español texto aquí";
WordUtils.wrap(s, 20);
```